# Flutter import dart:ffi not found

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to use `flutter_js` in order to run a javascript on web-browser (desktop, not mobile). When I run the app i get `/C:/src/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_js-0.6.0/lib/javascript_runtime.dart:3:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:ffi' import 'dart:ffi';`

Is there something that I do wrong or is it from the library?
If i run it on windows app, it works.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're using dart:ffi somewhere. But this library is used to access native code and it won't work on web. I'd suggest you to search for the place when you're importing dart:ffi and handle this with a conditional import.

UPD:
Maybe you have dart:ffi package somewhere in a project recources. That can be a reason of error also.

Comment: It is indeed in `windows/flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/path_provider_windows/test/path_provider_windows_test.dart` and `linux/flutter/ephemeral/.plugin_symlinks/path_provider_linux/lib/src/get_application_id_real.dart` . How should I handle them in this case?

Comment: Could you remove them from here? And see which import is broken if there are any